# PHP trying to login to MSSQL (windows authentication) with computer name instead of login name

Tags: php, sql-server-2005

I am trying to establish a connection to my company's MSSQL server with windows authentication , but it fails as it is trying to use my computer name as login instead of my login id. When logging in with the MS SQL Server Management the windows authentication works fine, but not with this PHP code:

```
<?php
// Server in the this format: <computer>\<instance name> or 
// <server>,<port> when using a non default port number
$serverName = "xxx";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"xxx");

/* Connect using Windows Authentication. */
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);


if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

// 
?>
```

The printout I get is the following:

> [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Login failed for
>   user 'xxx\T2002197$'. ) )

T2002197 is my computer name, not my login id, so of course it fails. How can I solve this? I am using WAMP.
Edited out some info, replaced with 'xxx'

Answer (score 7):

Aah problem solved! I changed the settings on my WAMP service (open service.msc in Windows) and made sure the service logged on the correct account. It works now.

Comment: that's great @suedish

Answer (score 0):

The manual says that per default the connection is using Windows Authentication and not the SQL Server authentication.

To bypass this you need to provide the uid and pwd options in your `$connectionInfo` data.

Se the manuals;

http://php.net/sqlsrv_connect

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff628167.aspx

Comment: Yes, but my account on the SQL server only allows me to use windows authentication, not the normal SQL Server Authentication. For example, in the SQL Server Management Studio, I can only login using windows authentication, it fails if I try to enter my login/password manually. So I need to make it work with the windows authentication somehow ...