# PHP 5.5 Connection with MS SQL SERVER 2008 R2 using WAMP

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, wamp

I need to connect to MS SQL SERVER 2008 R2 in PHP. I have followed certain tutorials but didnt solved my problems. i have used following code:

```
$serverName = "DARSHAN\SQLEXPRESS"; //serverName\instanceName, portNumber (default is 1433)
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"trail", "UID"=>"**", "PWD"=>"******");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
```

this code connects with my server but when I remove UID and PWD parameters connection dont get connected. I want to use windows authentication mode. Pls help me out.

Comment: Proberly double too:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13720237/php-trying-to-login-to-mssql-windows-authentication-with-computer-name-instead

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$serverName = "DARSHAN\SQLEXPRESS";     
// The connection will be attempted using Windows Authentication.
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"trail");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
     echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>
```

Source:

http://php.net/sqlsrv_connect

Comment: this doesnt works for me. I have tried this code before. I have already stated this in that if I remove UID and PWD parameters  it wont connect